# Forced installation method after IE add-on adobe flash stops supporting

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, adobe, add-on

IE11 start on stop support adobe flash player in the end of this year

but some of legacy system based on flash technology

so I want to know that are there any solutions to back up all necessary files before IE11 stops supporting flash?
and How to undo these files after IE11 stop supporting flash?

It's kind of like installing external add-ons

If possible, please feel free to submit ideas or experiences!

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no force installation method available that lets users keep using Flash after the end of support.

For enterprises seeking assistance with moving away from Adobe Flash Player, or needing continued support for line of business applications that may be dependent on it after 2020, Adobe is providing some [support options](https://blog.adobe.com/en/fpost/2020/update-for-enterprise-adobe-flash-player.html#gs.cvue0s).

References:

1. [UPDATE: Adobe Flash Player end of support on December 31, 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/update-adobe-flash-support)
2. [Update on Adobe Flash Player End of Support](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Our CTO created a fully encapsulated desktop application that allows our clients to run our Flash Xcelsius dashboards via our SaaS on their computers. We've tested it and it works for our 1,500 subscribers. Basically it is a browser that supports flash and allows a user without admin privileges to install the .exe and run our analytical dashboards when clicking various links from our browser based menu. Its like magic.

you might consider exploring Harman's similar offering here https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

Or let me know and I bet our CTO can moonlight a custom implementation for $10-12k and do it over 2 weekends.